# How can i convert this PDO statement to active record query in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

i have this PDO statement that works fine, but how can i convert it to active record in CodeIgniter?

My PDO statement is:

```
UPDATE mytable set total=bought+re_order-balance where retail_id=? and stock=? and stock_date=?
```

I tried this, but didnt work:

```
$data=array(                                                                                            
                    //some other fields
                    'total'=>'bought' + 're_order' - 'balance'                      
                    );

                $this->db->where('retail_id', $someid);
                $this->db->where('stock', $somestock);
                $this->db->where('stock_date', $somestock);
                $this->db->update('mytable',$data);
```

When i tried this, it didn't give any errors at the same time, it did not update my total field in the database. Any help pls. Thanks.

Comment: Are bought, re-order and balance strings or numbers?

Comment: They are all integers. They are also all fields in the same table.

Comment: So `$data = array( 'total' => ( $bought + $re-order - $balance ) ) so be a better fit.  At the moment you are trying to do math on strings

Comment: Also I prefer to make sure that I update using the unique ID of the table, are any of the where statements above using the tables unique ID?

Comment: Everything else is working, except for the addition. I dont think that solution would work, its a database field, putting a '$' makes it appear to be a variable.

Comment: OK but you have not supplied PHP with the values of the database field so how does it know what they are?  The code that you have provided is trying to create an array and place the strings into it.  If you want the values of those database fields then you will need to collect them first.

Comment: Yes, you have a point, but how does it works for the PDO statement? I didnt supply it with the values too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should build the needed query. The third parameter of `set()` method prevents data from escaping. You can read more abou it in the [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

```
$this->db->set('total', 'bought + re_order - balance', FALSE)
            ->where('retail_id', $someid)
            ->where('stock', $somestock)
            ->where('stock_date', $somestock)
            ->update('mytable');
```